# What is the difference between Unsafe.putAddress and Unsafe.putLong methods?

Tags: java

What is the difference between [Unsafe.putAddress(long address, long x)](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#putAddress(long,%20long)) method and [Unsafe.putLong(long address, long x)](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#putLong(long,%20long)) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc is pretty clear on that. For `putAddress()` it says:

> The number of bytes actually written at the target address may be determined by consulting #addressSize.

Whereas `putLong()` puts all bits of the long value.

In other words: an address *might* consume all bits of a long value, but doesn't *necessarily* have to! And then writing 64 bit to somewhere in memory is most likely not a good idea!

Therefore you need to able to distinguish these two use cases (writing *n bits out of 64 bits* and *writing exactly 64 bits*).

But to be specific, the javadoc for address size says:

> Report the size in bytes of a native pointer ... This value will be either 4 or 8.

So I guess, for all practical purpose, the two methods do the same. Because these days, (almost?!) all exist JVMs A) implement these methods and B) are 64 bit JVMs. ( so I assume that a 32 bit JVM would return 4 instead of 8 )

Comment: I think you are right. But I did a test for `putAddress()` and the method `addressSize()` always returns 8. When will the method `addressSize()` return 4?

Comment: I checked the hotspot code for the method `addressSize()`, the implement always return `sizeof(void*)`

Comment: So, making it a dependency of the underlying c++ compiler.

Comment: Yes, so it is clear now. For the method `putLong`, it awlays write a `long` value at the giving address. For `putAddress`, if the pointer in C++ compiler takes up 4 bytes, the value `x` will take up 4 bytes actually although `x` is a `long` parameter.